# CSS Transition Slide Menu on hover - ability to pin

Tags: css, transition

I have created a simple slide out menu from the left of a page by simply applying a CSS Transition to a div. The div has the following CSS class:

```
#slidingBox {
position: absolute;
width: 400px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #d9dada;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin-left: -390px;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
     #slidingBox:hover {
         margin-left: 0px;
     }
```

and it works okay. I have 10px of the menu on the side that when I hover over it the whole panel becomes viewable. However, as soon as I move my mouse off the DIV it scutters back into hidding... Fair enough, thats how this hover over transition works I guess. I would however like to put a little pin button in the corner I can click which will then keep the menu visible. Also, the menu currently appears 'over' the page on screen - when 'pinned' I would also like the  page underneath to resize so it is all viewable next to the pinned menu.

I could sit and play around with it for a bit but time is off the escence and if someone could point me in the right direction would be a great help!

I understand there are many different/better ways of doing what I have already done here so any other pointers would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to detect when the pin button is clicked and remove a class from #slidingBox to keep it expanded:

```
$('#pin-menu-button').click(function() {
  $('#slidingBox').toggleClass('no-pin');
});
```

The .no-pin class is what gives the sidebar menu the negative left margin.

To make the pinned menu and content display side-by-side you could use flexbox styling. Make sure you set display:flex; for the container around the sidebar and main content area.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/ytckjf4p/)

Comment: Thanks dude! I will take a more detailed look at that tomorrow. That makes a good degree of sense though! Will let you know how I get on! Many thanks!

Comment: Had to give it a try and I am struggling to get the first part working... Its like the hover takes over after I click the button (which is firing the event) then move away from the slidingBox...? I will take another look tomorrow!

Comment: @CJH added a fiddle to my answer, take a look and let me know if this is what you are looking to do.

Comment: Amazing - I was going to ask if you might do a fiddle...! I have loaded it though and unless I am going blind, I cannot see how to make the popout appear? :o/

Comment: ... Its as if the container carries on off the the left of the page beneath the Javascript pane next to it. I have had a 'fiddle' and it seems I need to change the #slidingbox width to something crazy like 420px!? It does now however work so will see if I can implement this tonight! Thanks a million!!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. If this is the functionality you are looking for don't forget to upvote and accept as answer. Cheers!

Comment: Was doing just as I received your note! Im not sure why the fiddle didn't work out of the box for me (im pressuming it does for you?) Managed to get it implemented on my project as well - again with some extra fudging of widths and margins, but happy this answer gives me everythign I needed! Many thanks again, this should be a neat surprise for my boss tomorrow!

Comment: Ooh, one more question... I was wondering if there was an alternative to flex that simply 'moves' the content to the right (with a horizontal scroll bar if needed) instead of 'flexing' it?

Comment: You could use jQuery to change the padding on the .content div in the click function: $('.content ').css( "padding-left", "200px" );

Comment: Thanks for that Steve... I havent had a chance to give this a good look yet (had some urgent work come in). Do I need to do anything to the items in object to stop them from wrapping to the next line instead of forcing the x-scroll bar from appearing. I managed to have a little play but cant seem to stop the line wrapping of my DIVs in Content?